# replacing a couple of Java loops, to a simple lambda but it looks like over complicated

Tags: java, java-stream

I am working with some apache POI files, it is working, and I am doing some refactoring on that, but I am facing a doubt with this code:

```
for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
                for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
                    for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
                        for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
                            for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                                String text = xwpfRun.getText(0);
                                if (text != null && text.contains(key)) {
                                    text = text.replace(key, replaces.get(key) == null ? "" : replaces.get(key));
                                    xwpfRun.setText(text, 0);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I try to replace this to a lambda the code looks like this :

```
    List<XWPFRun> collect = doc.getTables().stream().flatMap(xwpfTable -> xwpfTable.getRows().stream()
                    .flatMap(xwpfTableRow -> xwpfTableRow.getTableCells().stream().
                            flatMap(xwpfTableCell -> xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs().stream()
                                    .flatMap(xwpfParagraph -> xwpfParagraph.getRuns().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And for me this code is really complicated, as it does not return anything I need to split one last for each:

```
 for (XWPFRun xwpfRun : paragraph.getRuns()) {
                                String text = xwpfRun.getText(0);
                                if (text != null && text.contains(key)) {
                                    text = text.replace(key, replaces.get(key) == null ? "" : replaces.get(key));
                                    xwpfRun.setText(text, 0);
                                }
                            }
```

I am pretty sure there is a better and cleaner way to do this but I couldn't figure it out, do you have some ideas?

Comment: Not everything has to be replaced by lambdas and streams ... if your code operates on 5 nested sets (tables, rows, cells, paragraphs, runs) then 5 loops would be ok. As for the split, you could use `forEach(lambda)` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: I think you should create submethods first. Then after that maybe use streams instead of loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close to a readable solution.

You can "flatten" your `flatMap` calls like so:

```
doc.getTables().stream()
        .map(XWPFTable::getRows).flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(XWPFTableRow::getTableCells).flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(XWPFTableCell::getParagraphs).flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(XWPFParagraph::getRuns).flatMap(List::stream)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .forEach(xwpfRun -> {
            String text = xwpfRun.getText(0);
            if (text != null && text.contains(key)) {
                text = text.replace(key, replaces.get(key) == null ? "" : replaces.get(key));
                xwpfRun.setText(text, 0);
            }
});
```

Or you might prefer to replace each `.map().flatMap()` with a single `.flatMap`, which looks a bit more like your solution. For example:

```
.flatMap(table -> table.getRows().stream())
.flatMap(row -> row.getTableCells().stream())
...
```

You could also add a `.filter` instead of the `if` statement in the `forEach`, but that looked more complicated, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do the `flatMap` one by one
2. Simplify the code in the `forEach` at the end

   - remove the condition `text.contains(key)`
   - use `getOrDefault` instead of the ternary operation that will access twice the map in case of success

```
doc.getTables().stream()
            .flatMap(xwpfTable -> xwpfTable.getRows().stream())
            .flatMap(xwpfTableRow -> xwpfTableRow.getTableCells().stream())
            .flatMap(xwpfTableCell -> xwpfTableCell.getParagraphs().stream())
            .flatMap(xwpfParagraph -> xwpfParagraph.getRuns().stream())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .forEach(xwpfRun -> {
                String text = xwpfRun.getText(0);
                if (text != null) {
                    xwpfRun.setText(text.replace(key, replaces.getOrDefault(key, "")), 0);
                }
            });
```